# Who all are said to be Chiranjivis and their whereabouts?

Tags: life

In Hindu texts, we find that some people are said to be 'Chiranjivis', meaning that they will live till the end of the world or immortals. Can somebody let me know the names of all of them and where are they if they are still alive or any news about them in the recent past? Some of them I know are Ashwathama, Markandeya, Vashista, etc.