# Is it true that Kripa is in Himalayas?

Tags: mahabharata, kripa

We all know that Kripa is a chiranjevi.

From a famous preacher I heard that Kripa exists in Himalayas and is known to many people. Is it true?

Any evidence regarding this from Hindu texts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What happened to Kripa after Mahabharata War?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18419/1049) and [Who all are said to be Chiranjivis and their whereabouts?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3640/1049). Although the 2nd Qn is not fully answered. Hence that Qn might be opened and this can be closed to it. I already mistakenly used my closed vote to 2nd linked's linked duplicate and retracted.

Comment: @iammilind Those answers referring the sentences  in Mahabarata and are not giving any clues about their places of existence now.