# Is Ashwatthama still alive

Tags: mahabharata

Krishna cursed Ashwatthama with terrible leprosy that would haunt him for 3,000 years. Krishna further stated that Ashwatthama would not be helped by anyone or provided food or shelter.

Comment: Related [How did Aswathama get rid the sin of killing Upapandavas and curse of Lord Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14922/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer, can you add [this Qn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3640), as another generalised duplicate. Flagged helpful but link not added.

Comment: @iammilind Added.